# How to know where iOS app installed from (using Enterprise distribution)

Tags: ios

With Enterprise Distribution, I provided a link to .ipa on the internet, and sent it to customers. 
After a customer install the .ipa via that link. Is it posible to know where the app was installed from? Any code added or any way to know that?